# Question regarding a particular type of graph

Tags: graphs, graph-traversal, adjacency-matrix

Let $G = (V,E)$ be a directed graph where every vertex is represented by an $n$ bit string. The edges are represented by two polynomial-sized circuits $S$ and $P$. There is an edge from $u$ to $v$ if and only if $S(u) = v$ and $P(v) = u$. I am trying to prove:

- $G$ just contains paths, cycles, or isolated vertices.
- Let $A_{G}$ be the adjacency matrix of $G$. Consider $H = \frac{1}{2} A_{G}$. Then, $||H||_{2} = 1$.

Comment: The out-degree and in-degree of each vertex are at most 1. Does that help?

Comment: Why do we need to divide by $1/2$ for the second case? Isn't $||A_{G}||_{2} = 1$ already?

Comment: I am guessing that this relates to the fact that there could be vertices of degree 2.

Comment: As in, a vertex which has out-degree 1 and also a self-loop?

Comment: No, as in all vertices in a (directed) cycle.

Comment: Which vertex would have degree 2 in a directed cycle? Wouldn't all the vertices still have (out)-degree 1?

Comment: Their in-degree + out-degree would be 2.

Comment: Look, if you can prove that $\|A_G\| = 1$, then the $1/2$ factor isn't needed (indeed, *has* to be removed). So to resolve the issue, all you have to do is to calculate $\|A_G\|$.

Comment: By the way, are we guaranteed that $S(u) = v$ iff $P(v) = u$?

Comment: Yes, we are. guaranteed that

Comment: You should probably update the question with this information.

Comment: Updated. I computed $||A_{G}||$ by taking a few example graphs. But it would have been good to get a general procedure for calculating $||A_{G}||$. My intuition was that $||A_{G}||$ takes the form of a permutation matrix, and hence, $||A_{G}|| = 1$. Is that correct?

Comment: The question is asking you to prove that $\|A_G\|=1$. Hence you should try to find why that should hold. Perron–Frobenius theory might come in useful here (or might be an overkill).